# Not attaching files when using ajax progress bar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working with Mail attachements. I can send mails and attachement using plain [MAIL CLASS](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:363f), But When I use this [AJAX FILE UPLOAD](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/) together with the mail class I'm getting attachements but not the file that I have uploaded to my server. Eg. Test.doc. On my receiving email I do get emails and attachement sent by my contact form but it is not attaching the right file. Instead of Test.doc What I'm receiving is a plain "uploads" file without any extensions.

**Controller.php**

```
 $allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip', 'doc', 'docx', 'xps');

    if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], './uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
}


        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {

            $mail = new Mail();

            $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');

            $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');

            $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');

            $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');

            $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');

            $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');

            $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');             

            $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));

            $mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);

            $mail->setSender($this->request->post['name']);

            $mail->addAttachment('./uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name']);

            $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

            $mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

            $mail->send();

            $this->redirect($this->url->link('services/printing/success'));


        }
$this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('services/printing');
```

**FORM**

```
    <form id="upload" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="drop">
                Drop Here

                <a>Browse</a>
                <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
            </div>

            <ul>
                <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
            </ul>
    </form>
```

'./uploads/ is the folder where the files uploaded to my server go. It is in the root directory. e.g. public_html/uploads. I can see the files uploaded to uploads folder. Eg. Test.doc, test.docx. test.zip etc.

This is what i'm getting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `$_FILES['upl']['name']` in `$mail->addAttachment('./uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name']);` isn't there anymore. Try passing the filename through a variable.

```
$fname = './uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $fname)){
    echo '{"status":"success", "fname" : "'.$fname.'"}';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I followed what you suggested but still the same output.

Comment: Have you changed `$mail->addAttachment('./uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name']);` to `$mail->addAttachment($_POST['fname'])` (or whatever method you're using)?

Comment: Yes I did it like this: $mail->addAttachment($this->request->post['fname']); but now I don't get any attachments

Comment: Try this - in $mail->addAttachment() type in the file path and name manually (but use a full path, don't start with ./), make sure the file is in the directory - if the file gets attached it means there's something wrong either with your path to the file or the file name. 

My first guess was to pass the file name, because the attachment you get would suggest, that the script is trying to attach the directory /uploads/ as a file, which results in an empty file.

Comment: Yes using a full path does work. $mail->addAttachment('/home4/user/public_html/uploads/tests.docx'); My receiving email does receive an attachement of tests.docx. What might be causing the problem?

Comment: The path is invalid. You need to add the full path. Change `'./uploads/'` to `BASE_PATH . '/uploads/'` and in your main index file add: `define('BASE_PATH', (realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) == '/' ? '' : realpath(dirname(__FILE__))));`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36862/discussion-between-aleksander-owrew-and-demic0de)